# My car won't start after recharging battery

Tags: starting, vw, golf

I have a 2016 golf sti. I had to recharge my battery due to a stupid mistake I made. I'v only got an old 4amp charger. After 4 hours I get all the warnings my manual said would happen but the it won't start. It even tells me I should Go For a drive to charge battery. lol. Any ideas . thanks

Comment: All good now. Stopped checking it every 2hours and let the charger run for 6.
I an idiot I no.lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe detailing your "stupid mistake" would help us diagnose the problem.  But a 4 amp charger may take a while to bring the battery up to starter potential.  By the way, you haven't told us whether you charged thru the negative clamp onto the engine block or direct to the negative battery terminal.  Also, what happens when you try to start, like, do you hear the starter, and what sound does it make?

Comment: I'll remember to take your advice if/when I make the mistake agian. (left the key in I think) thanks